# Add share links to all blog posts on homepage

Tags: plugin-recommendation, social-sharing

I need to figure out a way to add share links to each blog post on the homepage. This way users can share specific posts without actually going into the post. Is there a way to do this easily through a WP plugin?

The only tricky thing to me is they will be sharing URLs from pages which they are not actually on so I'm unsure how to proceed with that.. does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Plugin recommendations are [off topic](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1217/73) now. Please rephrase your question: If you ask how to write such a code – fine. But show us what you have tried already, some code or research efforts. Oh, and welcome to WordPress Stack Exchange!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option to do this in Jetpack, if you have sharing tured on. Just click on "Front Page, Archive Pages"... etc

[image: jetpack sharing]

Then it'll show up on the homepage, for example on my homepage:

[image]

Comment: You're welcome, I was glad to find the answer myself!